# Engineering reliability questions okay?

Tags: discussion

Title about says it all; reliability calculations are *pretty* much stats/probability questions, but the lingo is a bit different and of course there are other nuances.

More generally, are questions about X specifically (where X is a form of applied stats/probability/analysis) okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please try. To the extent possible do make the question application agnostic and if providing the context is important to understand the question then do provide an explanation for the jargon that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try, at least they will be closed. Still try to avoid jargon and give some references if possible.